# Dataframe merge in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I want to merge two dataframes in python with pandas.
Here's what they look like:

df_a

```
   Nr1  
1  234 
2  256  
3  678
```

df_b

```
   Nr1  Nr2
1  567  9.345
2  256  6.678
3  678  4.123
4  478  3.456
```

I'm trying to perform a "left join" so that I get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   Nr1  Nr2
1  234  nan
2  256  6.678
3  678  4.123
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
df_a.merge(df_b, on='Nr1', how='left')
```

or

```
df_a.merge(df_b, left_on='Nr1', right_on='Nr1', how='left')
```

These don't work, however - the results look like this:

```
   Nr1  Nr2
1  234  nan
2  256  0.000
3  678  0.000
```

Both `Nr1` columns are the same dtype. Why are there zeroes in the column `Nr2`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your question. Both `merge` work correctly and result in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_a.merge(df_b, left_on='Nr1', right_on='Nr1', how='inner' )
```